# Options for installing scikit-learn

Tags: python, pip, scikit-learn

From http://scikit-learn.org/dev/install.html#building-scikit-learn-with-pip

> ```
> pip install --user --install-option="--prefix=" -U scikit-learn
> ```
>
> The --user flag asks pip to install scikit-learn in the $HOME/.local
>   folder therefore not requiring root permission. This flag should make
>   pip ignore any old version of scikit-learn previously installed on the
>   system while benefiting from system packages for numpy and scipy.
>   Those dependencies can be long and complex to build correctly from
>   source.
>
> The --install-option="--prefix=" flag is only required if Python has a
>   distutils.cfg configuration with a predefined prefix= entry.

1. In `man pip` for my `pip 1.5.4`,  why are there no `--user` `--install-option` `-U` options, although the above command can run?

   For `--install-option`,

   - what does it mean?
   - how shall I find out "if Python has a distutils.cfg configuration with a predefined prefix= entry"?
   - What is "distutils.cfg" used for?

   For `-U`, what does it mean?
2. If I want to install scikit-learn to my system default directory,
   what command shall I run? Is it

   ```
   pip install scikit-learn
   ```

   ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should definitely upgrade `pip`, as the current version is 6.1.1. Run

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

to do that. I wouldn't necessarily trust what `man pip` has to say, as it may be for an ancient version of `pip`. Instead, use the docs [here](https://pip.pypa.io).

`-U` and `--upgrade` are the same thing. `--user` is separate.

You don't need to worry about the `prefix` thing, or `distutils.cfg`. You'd know if you have them, because it's something you'd have to set up manually. So, just try running

```
pip install scikit-learn -U --user
```

after you've upgraded `pip`, and hopefully everything will go smoothly.

---

If you're on a Linux or Unix system (like OS X), or you have the GNU command-line tools installed on Windows, and you want `pip` to upgrade **all** of your packages, this command should work in bash:

```bsh
pip list | awk '{print $1}' | while read -r package; do sudo -H pip install -U "$package"; done
```

`pip list` prints out the name and version of each package installed (and, at least on my Ubuntu 14.10 system, that includes everything, system- or `pip`-installed), along with its version number in parentheses. `awk '{print $1}'` splits each line on whitespace, and returns the first field (the package name). The `while` loop reads each incoming line (the package name) and calls `sudo -H pip install -U packagename`, which will look to see if the package is up-to-date, and if not it will upgrade it. I'm assuming system packages like those installed by Ubuntu won't be upgraded, as they're not listed in PyPI, but I killed the command before I found out.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to upgrade all installed python packages, without upgrading them one by one?

Comment: @Tim see my edit - yes, it is possible with a little bit of command-line-fu. *Should* you blindly upgrade everything? That's up to you. You can always generate the list of packages in a text file `pip list | awk '{print $1}' | cat >> piplist`, then go through it manually and delete anything you don't want to upgrade. Then, run `cat piplist | while read ...` and it should do its thing.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to install [Anaconda](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkg-docs.html), which will allow you to easily install scikit-learn