# Import Error on importing sklearn in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, anaconda

I am new to python and installed it in windows OS and while following Google's machine learning tutorial on youtube, i encountered an error while importing the scikit package.

I installed the Anaconda package as shown in the tutorial but when importing sklearn i get an import error.

```
import sklearn
```

i also tried

```
from sklearn import tree
```

This is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Raj Asha\Desktop\hello-world.py", line 2, in <module>
    from sklearn import tree
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'
```

python version is 3.6.1

link to tutorial video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cKxRvEZd3Mw

Comment: Post the import statement used and also post how did you install the sklearn don't post video links

Comment: What is does the import error say? Paste it into your question.

Comment: Remove anaconda and Try pip install scikit-learn , pip install numpy , pip install scipy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Options for installing scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29658890/options-for-installing-scikit-learn)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you use Windows? From the error that you posted I say yes.

Open your terminal (cmd) and try these before you try to import the sklearn.

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

or

```
conda install scikit-learn
```

Also make sure your have numpy and scipy:

```
pip install numpy 
pip install scipy
```

**EDIT**

The conda error means that the conda is not in you PATH environment.

To solve this, Uninstall Anaconda and install it again, this time by selecting BOTH the options in the installation instruction as shown:

[image]

**EDIT 2**

If you do not have `pip` then, download from [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) the `get-pip.py` file and then use cmd to run `python get-pip.py` inside the folder in which get-pip.py is saved

Comment: also pip install scipy

Comment: @sera 'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @Raj I edited my answer in order to solve the conda error. However, you can pip to install sklearn

Comment: @sera Even pip is not recognized as internal or external command

Comment: @Raj download from [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) the get-pip.py file and then use cmd to run "python get-pip.py" inside the folder in which get-pip.py is saved

Answer (score 1):

I tried multiple solutions, but none of them worked.
I installed the wheel files:

```
scipy-1.8.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
numpy-1.22.3+mkl-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
scikit_learn-1.0.2-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
```

But I got error in: `import sklearn`

In my case, I was able to solve this by installing the `whl` file of the joblib (before, do: `pip install wheel`).

Download: https://github.com/wikimedia/research-ores-wheels/blob/master/joblib-0.14.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl

```
pip uninstall joblib
pip install .../joblib-0.14.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

Answer (score 0):

update your anaconda and python. I had the same problem. had to change my windows from 7 to 10 because python 3.9 doesn't support windows 7 or earlier anymore